# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make it recognize when a message contains only one letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a reaction for my bot. Whenever someone says only the letter "f", I want it to send an image:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('f') or message.content.startswith('F'):
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('f.png'))
```

However, this code makes it send the image whenever someone says something that starts with "f". I want it to send the image whenever someone says something that contains only the letter "f". Not sure how to do that, any tips?

Comment: Given your use of `message.content.startswith('f')`, for a message _starting with_ f but potentially having subsequent characters, can you think of any way to adapt that to your task?

Comment: Do you know how to get the contents of the message? And how to get the length of a string? And how to compare one string to another? That's all you need to do, it's not clear what you're stuck on.

Comment: You should not start dpy, when you don't know enough python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic python

```py
>>> "foo".starswith("f")
True
>>> "foo" == "f"
False
```

You can use the same principle in the `on_message` event

```py
if message.content.lower() == "f":
    # Send the image
```